Тире или запятая перед «только»?
Сейчас же не было ни гордости, ни радости (?) только ощущение одиночества.
Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно? Могут ли быть правильными оба варианта?


Основным вариантом будет обособление тире:

Сейчас же не было ни гордости, ни радости — только ощущение одиночества.
Здесь обособление  присоединительной конструкции в конце предложенияс помощью тире.
У Розенталя это тема  § 24. Присоединительные конструкции
6. Присоединительные конструкции могут включаться в 
высказывание без союзов: Довольно поздно явился ещё гость, 
во фраке (Герц.); Он умер, в Томске (М. Г.); Когда Филипп 
вышел на кухню, умываться, Анфиса Петровна спросила… (Фед.); 
Ночью я стою у орудия, дневальным (Кат.); Я опять промолчал, 
должно быть от изумления (Пауст.).
Часто при этом используется тире: Видел я на днях 
«Крокодиловы слёзы» — бездарнейшая пятиактная белиберда 
(Ч.);


Обособление запятой также допускается:

Сейчас же не было ни гордости, ни радости, только ощущение одиночества.
Выбор делается по контексту. При обособлении тире обе части предложения одинаково значимы, а при обособлении запятой интонационно выделена последняя часть.
